# Compiler Error Message: CS0433: What spawns the TEMP .DLL files?

Tags: compiler-errors, message

I have a legacy website that gets the following error when a particular page is called:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'InfoSource.SendMailNonUser' exists in 
both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\b128c7fb\67fde62e\App_Web_-ur1gs2w.dll' 
and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\b128c7fb\67fde62e\assembly\dl3\a529b440\007022c7_37ebc701\InfoSource.DLL'
```

I have deleted the files in the Temp folder and they just rebuild with a different file name starting with `App_Web_xxxxxx.dll`.

I need to find out what program file is spawning the App_Web dll file and kill it to stop the duplication of types. I have searched the sites files but find no .dll files with a Web_App name.

Does anyone know how to determine which file causes the build of the TEMP dll?

The site is a classic ASP site built on .NETFramework 2.0 (C# code behind).

Comment: I went go into "References" and remove the reference for InfoSource.dll and it started to work again in Visual Studio's. Problem is, how do I remove that same reference in the actual website? I think references in Visual Studio's are kept in the project file. Since we are not using a project file on the production website, how do I find and get rid of that reference ?
 
Thanks,
 
Eric

Comment: If you have removed the reference from the project file, then build the project. Now the .exe or .dll's generated, do not have this references anymore.